# Where can I find latest Spring DM Maven archetype?

Tags: spring, maven, blueprint-osgi, spring-dm

Last night I tried to create new spring-osgi-bundle-archetype.

At first I found out that 1.2.1 was provided with Spring 2.5.x. After creation I tried to compile an empty project. The process ended with error that log4j.osgi could not been found.

My question is: "Is there some Maven archetype which provides access to Spring 3.2.4, which seems to be latest version with OSGI support?"

I read that Spring DM become a Gemini Blueprint, but can't  find any examples how I can combine them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring DM moved and is now Gemini Blueprint: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/rt.gemini.blueprint 
Spring DM Server became Eclipse Virgo.

From the reference: https://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/reference/1.0.2.RELEASE/html/eclipse-migration.html

> In late 2009, as a member of the Gemini project proposal, SpringSource
>   contributed Spring Dynamic Modules (also known as Spring OSGi) project
>   to the Eclipse Foundation. Spring DM v2 code base has been moved to
>   Eclipse.org along with its issue tracker and forum. The project became
>   dual licensed under Apache License and EPL. While the name has
>   changed, the code and its functionality remained the same. Existing
>   Spring DM applications can be easily migrated to Eclipse Gemini
>   Blueprint as mentioned in the migration guide. While the project name
>   has changed (to Eclipse Gemini Blueprint) and significant efforts have
>   been made to reflect this in the project documentation and resources,
>   there might be places that we have missed; if you find any, please
>   report them to us.

AFAIK there is no existing archetype, but creating a maven project for DM is not that complicated. The more complicated thing would be the whole new environment you are working with.

I would recommend you the "greenpages example" which is very useful if you are new to osgi/blueprint: https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/greenpages-documentation-2.4.0.RELEASE/docs/htmlsingle/greenpages-guide.html